# Tensorflow error only when running reloaded model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror, loss-function

unfortunately, I have run into one of those mistier tensorflow error messages again. As the error message is not much to go by, maybe someone here can help me debug this.

I am running an MTL-model, consisting of a joint autoencoder + classifier. It's trained with CCE loss and a custom version of MSE that multiplies the MSE loss with a constant value.

```
def mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    
    # get normal cce loss:
    mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    mse_loss = mse(y_true, y_pred)
    
    # apply some gain:
    factor = tf.constant(100, dtype=tf.float32)
    mse_loss = tf.math.multiply(mse_loss, factor)
    
    return mse_loss
```

I add the loss via  `model.add_loss(mse_loss(y_true=y_true_d, y_pred=out_d))` at the end of my model definition.

Training the model goes fine. After training, I save the model as a .h5-file.

After reloading the model from the .h5-file, however, when trying to run 'model.fit(...)' or 'model.predict(...)' I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-2fbfa2a2b989> in <module>
     11 
     12 # Train the model:
---> 13 history = model.fit(
     14       train_dataset,
     15       steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,

~\.conda\envs\Branding_tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

~\.conda\envs\Branding_tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py in size_internal(input, name, optimize, out_type)
    803           (sparse_tensor.SparseTensor, sparse_tensor.SparseTensorValue))):
    804     input = ops.convert_to_tensor(input)
--> 805     np_out_type = out_type.as_numpy_dtype
    806     num_elements = np.prod(input._shape_tuple(), dtype=np_out_type)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    807     return ops.convert_to_tensor(num_elements, dtype=out_type)

AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.compat.v1.size" "                 f"(type TFOpLambda).

'str' object has no attribute 'as_numpy_dtype'

Call arguments received by layer "tf.compat.v1.size" "                 f"(type TFOpLambda):
  • input=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 40000, 4), dtype=float32)
  • name='mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/num_elements/'
  • out_type='int32'
```

The error seems to be occurring somewhere in the custom loss function, but the fact that it only occurs on the reloaded model makes no sense to me.

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Do you get the same error without adding the loss function?

Comment: No, it works fine running and reloading the model with the standart mse loss, if i comment out the `model.add_loss` line and compile with `loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'mse']` instead of `loss=['categorical_crossentropy', None]`